# Creating javascript class in NextJS library that uses server side code throws error on frontend even though not imported

Tags: next.js

I am working on a NextJS project and I am building a library that I can re-use for other projects. In the library, I am creating a javascript class as below:

```
export class EmailManager {

    private nodemailer: any = null;
    private transporter : any = null;

    constructor()
    {
        if (typeof window === typeof undefined)
        {
            this.nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
            this.transporter = this.nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_HOST,
                port: parseInt(process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_PORT as string),
                secure: false,
            })
        }
    }

    async send(recipient: string, subject: string, content: string, from_address : string = process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_FROM as string) {
        const info = await this.transporter.sendMail({
            from: from_address,
            to: recipient,
            subject: subject,
            html: content
        })

    }
}
```

The nextjs library is built using the below command:

```
npm run build:esm && npm run build:cjs && npm run build:css
```

In my API function, where I need the class I am then doing the following:

```
const EmailManager= require('devso-nextjs-library').EmailManager;
const emailManager = new EmailManager();
```

I know things like nodemail is a server side only library, so can only be used in API routes, getServerSideProps etc. I am not importing or using this class specifically in the frontend, although other unrelated functions are imported from the library, but nothing that is using the nodemail class is imported into the frontend, but I am getting the below error as soon as any page loads:

```
../my-nextjs-library/lib/cjs/classes/EmailManager.js:45:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'nodemailer'
  43 |         this.transporter = null;
  44 |         if (typeof window === typeof undefined) {
> 45 |             this.nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
  46 |             this.transporter = this.nodemailer.createTransport({
  47 |                 host: process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_HOST,
  48 |                 port: parseInt(process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_PORT),

Import trace for requested module:
../my-nextjs-library/lib/cjs/index.js
./src/components/TopNav.tsx
./src/pages/index.tsx

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the issue is :

> typeof undefined

instead of just using:

> "undefined"

I'd also rather suggest using import instead of require (if you're not limited by js versions contraints). Try this: (as I can't test your scenario with a fiddle or something to test my suggestion)

```
constructor()
{
    if (typeof window === "undefined")
    {
        import("nodemailer").then((nodemailer) => {
            this.nodemailer = nodemailer;
            this.transporter = this.nodemailer.createTransport({
                host: process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_HOST,
                port: parseInt(process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_PORT as string),
                secure: false,
            });
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Failed to load nodemailer module or -something else - ERROR choose something :)", error);
        });
    }
}
```

For the net error mentioned, I would suggest trying to escape the need for Node's serverside libs (as net) by targeting a very scpecific lib first, say, one to get STMP to config well known services on createTransport:

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    import("nodemailer/lib/well-known/services")
.then((wellKnown) => {
      import("nodemailer").then((nodemailer) => {
        const { SMTP } = wellKnown;
        this.nodemailer = nodemailer;
        this.transporter = this.nodemailer.createTransport({
          host: process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_HOST,
          port: parseInt(process.env.NEXT_EMAIL_PORT as string),
          secure: false,
          service: SMTP,
        });
      });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(
        "Failed to load nodemailer module or -something else - ERROR choose something :)",
        error
      );
});
```

}

so in compilation only nodemailer's specific dep is checked and not all of the other Node's possible deps. (hopefully this gets it working, if not, I'd like a minimal public repo to reproduce it), sorry for the delay.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately. It seems to just move the issue into somewhere else within the nodemailer. Now getting the following:
`node_modules/nodemailer/lib/fetch/index.js:10:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'net'`

Comment: @Boardy I'll update my answer, please give it a go (probably by specifying some targeted module that doesn't rely on Node's lib like net, can fix this)

Comment: I managed to figure out, what you had worked, but there were other dependencies within nodemailer that nextjs tries to bundle into the client side code. So I had to update the nextjs config to remove all nodemailer depencies such as net, dns, tls etc to not be included in the nextjs client bundle

Comment: @Boardy nice! I was just adding another possible way haha glad to hear it!